# Rails: why is calling to_a on a string not valid in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, rake

I'm trying to decrypt a bunch of passwords for a database migration. I've got some older Rails code (actually a Runner script) that decrypts them just fine. But putting that same code into a Rake task causes the task to fail with ...undefined method `to_a' for "secretkey":String...

Why would calling to_a on a string be invalid in a Rake task, but perfectly valid in a Runner script?

```
require 'openssl'

KEY = 'secretkey'

  namespace :import do
  task :users => :environment do
      def decrypt_password(pw)

          cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('bf-ecb')
          cipher.decrypt
          cipher.key = KEY.to_a.pack('H*')    <<--------- FAILS RIGHT HERE on to_a

          data = data.to_a.pack('H*')
          data = cipher.update(data)
          data << cipher.final
          unpad(data)

      end
   end

   ... other methods
end
```

(Rails 3.0.0, Ruby 1.9.2)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In ruby 1.9, String no longer has a `to_a` method. Your older code probably used Ruby 1.8, which did.

Comment: True, yet @tihm 's answer is helping more because it actually answers the question.

Answer (score 20):

To duplicate the 1.8.7 functionality:

```
1.8.7 > 'foo'.to_a # => ['foo']
```

You would use:

```
1.9.3 > 'foo'.lines.to_a # => ['foo']
```

The other answers suggest #chars, which is not the same:

```
1.9.9 > 'foo'.chars.to_a # => ['f', 'o', 'o']
```

Comment: thanks! was having this error with an old TextMate bundle

Comment: isn't  `'foo'.lines.to_a` the same as `'foo'.lines`

Comment: Equally you can just do `['foo']` or `Array.new('foo')`. The main benefit in 1.8.7 was that when calling `my_var.to_a` it didn't matter if `my_var` was a single string or was already an array of strings (because `to_a` is effectively a no-op on Array). None of these options provide that same flexibility, unfortunately.

Answer (score 9):

String objects do not have `to_a`.  See here:
http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/String.html

You can use:

```
"foo".chars.to_a
```

Which results in:

```
["f","o","o"]
```

Comment: this is probably more efficient

Answer (score 1):

```
"abcd".each_char.map {|c| c }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are parsing to a serialization object to use on apis, you could:

```
JSON.parse "[]" # => []
```